# Understanding how axios works in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, networking, axios

so I've come across a problem today that I do not really understand.
Here it is: 
So basically I have for backend a node js server with mongoDB and when I call my first component I do the following:
in the constructor I call a function that will return an array will all users except the one that is logged in

```
fetchUsers = () => {
        axios.get(userAPI) //Array from all users in DB
        .then((res)=>{
          for(var k = 0; k <(res.data.length); k++){
            console.log(this.state.idUser)
            if(this.state.idUser==res.data[k]._id){
                console.log("forget same user")
            }
            else
            {
              realUsers.push(res.data[k])
            }
          }
          console.log(realUsers)
        })
```

What I do not understand is in this function this.state.idUser is equal to the id of the user logged in, and it's not null, however when I call a second axios function in the constructor that takes for URL a link+this.state.idUser this time the state of idUser is null.

```
historyUsers = () =>{
       axios({
         method:'GET',
         url : urlArrayHistory+this.state.idUser
       })
       .then((response)=>{
         console.log("response de historyVote",response)
         const realUsersId = []
         for(let p=0; p<realUsers.length;p++){
           realUsersId.push(realUsers[p]._id)
         }
         for(let k = 0;k<response.data[0].historyVote.length;k++){
           if(realUsersId.includes(response.data[0].historyVote[k])){
             console.log("it's in",realUsers)
             realUsers.pop(k)
             console.log(realUsers)
           }
           else{
             console.log("ain't in")
           }
         }
       })
     }
```

What I want at the end is that it compares the realUsers array that are all users on my app
and the array from historyVote that are all users that the current user (the one logged in) has already met.

Thanks for any help :)
If you need more code or something let me know.

EDIT : Here is a full code of my component

```
  const userAPI = 'http://localhost:5050/api/new/users'
  const urlHistory = 'http://localhost:5050/api/vote/historyvote/'
  const urlArrayHistory = 'http://localhost:5050/api/vote/array/'
  const realUsers = []


const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;


export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.position = new Animated.ValueXY()
        this.state={
          currentIndex : 0,
          idUser : null,
          nameUser : null,
          scoreUser : null,
          currentAdverseId :"",
          currentToken : this.props.screenProps.jwt,
          readyRender : 0,
          voteHistory : [],
        }
this.infoUserAdverse = {
          name :"",
          age : "",
          Score:"",
          idAdverse :""
        }
}
retrieveId = () =>{ //Get back the Id of current logged in user from the token
      const header = {
        'authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.screenProps.jwt
      }
      console.log(header)
      axios.get('http://localhost:5050/api/posts',{
        headers : header
      })
      .then((response) =>{
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({idUser: response.data._id})
        console.log(this.state.idUser)
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
      historyUsers = () =>{
        axios({
          method:'GET',
          url : urlArrayHistory+this.state.idUser
        })
        .then((response)=>{
          console.log("response de historyVote",response)
          const realUsersId = []
          for(let p=0; p<realUsers.length;p++){
            realUsersId.push(realUsers[p]._id)
          }
          for(let k = 0;k<response.data[0].historyVote.length;k++){
            if(realUsersId.includes(response.data[0].historyVote[k])){
              console.log("it's in",realUsers)
              realUsers.pop(k)
              console.log(realUsers)
            }
            else{
              console.log("ain't in")
            }
          }
        })
      }
      fetchUsers = () => {
        axios.get(userAPI) //Array from all users in DB
        .then((res)=>{
          for(var k = 0; k <(res.data.length); k++){
            if(this.state.idUser==res.data[k]._id){
                console.log("forget same user")
            }
            else
            {
              realUsers.push(res.data[k])
            }
          }
          console.log(realUsers)
        })
      }

      apiFetchId = () => 
      {
        const newHeader = {
        'authorization':'Bearer '+this.state.currentToken
      }
        axios.get('http://localhost:5050/api/new/'+this.state.idUser,{
        headers: newHeader
      })
      .then((res)=>{
        console.log(res)
        this.setState({
          nameUser:res.data.name,
          scoreUser:res.data.Score,
          voteHistory:res.data.historyVote
        })
      })
      }
componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchUsers()
        this.apiFetchId()
        //this.historyUsers()
        //this.renderUsers()
    }
renderUsers = () => {
        return realUsers.map((item, i) => {
          if(i< this.state.currentIndex){
            return null
          }
          else if (i == this.state.currentIndex){
            console.log("render users cas 2")
            this.infoUserAdverse=realUsers[i]
            return (
              <Animated.View
                {...this.PanResponder.panHandlers}
                key={item._id} style={[this.rotateAndTranslate , { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 220, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position: 'absolute' }]}>
                  <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.likeOpacity, transform: [{ rotate: '-30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
                    <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'green', color: 'green', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>++</Text>
                  </Animated.View> 
                  <Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.dislikeOpacity, transform: [{ rotate: '30deg' }], position: 'absolute', top: 50, right: 40, zIndex: 1000 }}>
                    <Text style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', color: 'red', fontSize: 32, fontWeight: '800', padding: 10 }}>--</Text>
                  </Animated.View>

                <Image
                  style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 20 }}
                  source={{uri:"http://localhost:5050/"+item.userImage}} />
              </Animated.View>

            )
          }
          else {
            console.log("render users cas 3")
            return (
              <Animated.View
                key={item._id} style={[{
                  opacity: this.nextCardOpacity,
                  transform: [{scale: this.nextCardScale}], 
                  height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 220, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position: 'absolute' }]}>
                <Image
                  style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 20 }}
                  source={item.uri} />

              </Animated.View>
            )
          }
        }).reverse()
      }


      addHisotryUser =  () => {
        let urlHistory2 = urlHistory+this.state.idUser
        console.log(urlHistory2)
        axios({ 
          method: 'PATCH',
          url: urlHistory2,
          //headers: {authorization: 'Bearer '+this.state.currentToken},
          data: { 
            userId: this.infoUserAdverse._id,
          } 
        })
        .then((res)=>{
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err)
        })
      }
```

Comment: First of all, why are you loading your app data inside the constructor? That should be loaded either in `componentDidMount()` or in a `useEffect()` hook.

Comment: add your full source of component

Comment: Hello, I don't really know why I did that, I just wanted to make users Users would render before it displays on the screen but I just moved in the ComponentDidMount() and it's working.

Comment: I can add the full source yes but I hope you will be able to understand all, I'm kinda a beginner in computer science and what I write may not be easy to understand for everyone I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is due to the state being set after you start calling your Axios methods.

In the first Axios query, `fetchUsers`, the server is contacted first and only after a response has been received does the code look at `state.idUser`. In the second query, `historyUsers`, `state.idUser` is needed immediately to construct a URL, before contacting the server. The delay in `fetchUsers` would be enough for the state to have been set in the meantime.

Make sure that in your constructor, before you call `fetchUsers` or `historyUsers`, you have in fact already set `this.state = { idUser: xxx }`.

Comment: Okay, thanks I understand perfectly, I'm retrieving the ID user from the token he gets when loggin in, so what I need to do is in my constructor call the function to get back the userId from the token right?

Comment: As long as you make sure that `state.idUser` is in fact set before calling any of your Axios methods.

Comment: I feel like my componentDidMount() is called while my constructor() is also being called do you know why?

Comment: Your component is constructed, then mounted. Both things happen at the start of the component lifecycle. It's best to set your state in the constructor, then do your Axios requests in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Okay, but I thought componentDidMount would be run when the component has finished rendering. So what I do in my constructor is get the id of the user to set the state. However, after if I try to fetch data to display on my screen but I put the function in the componentDidMount() it will not use the state id null and not the one updated from the constructor.